# Mapping composite key to two foreign keys

Tags: nhibernate, foreign-keys, composite

I've got the following two tables:

```
Jobs
--------
JobNo
DivisionID

NCRs
--------
ID
JobNo
SpoilageJobNo
DivisionID
```

JobNo and DivisionID make up a composite key in the Jobs table (I know, but unfortunately it has to be a composite key, as it's actually a view that's pulling data from 4 different databases), and I need to join this key to the NCRs table on both JobNo and SpoilageJobNo.

I've tried the following mappings:

```
<class name="Job" table="v_Jobs">
    <composite-id name="Key">
        <key-property name="JobNo"></key-property>
        <key-many-to-one name="Division" class="Division" column="DivisionID"/>
    </composite-id>

    <bag name="NCRs">
        <key>
            <column name="JobNo"></column>
            <column name="DivisionID"></column>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="NCR"/>
    </bag>

    <bag name="SpoilageNCRs">
        <key>
            <column name="SpoilageJobNo"></column>
            <column name="DivisionID"></column>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="NCR"/>
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="NCR" table="NCRs">
    <id name="ID">
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="Division"
                 class="Division"
                 column="DivisionID">
    </many-to-one>

    <many-to-one name="Job"
                 class="Job"
                 column="JobNo">
    </many-to-one>

    <many-to-one name="SpoilageJob"
                 class="Job"
                 column="SpoilageJobNo">
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

But I just get the error `Foreign key (FK480F1031931B2CA4:NCRs [JobNo])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (v_Jobs [JobNo, DivisionID])`

Comment: the mapping in the update should give an error because DivisionID is mapped twice no?

Comment: Nope, it works fine. Presumably because DivisionID is defined as a column within a many-to-one key, rather than as a property on its own? I do actually have another mapping for Division in that hbm file as well. Ah the joys of composite keys. :P

Comment: try to insert a new NCR object with the references set, I would be surprised if it does not throw IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct, I did have that issue when creating/updating an NCR. I just went with a dirty fix of creating two separate property mappings for JobNo and SpoilageJobNo and marking the many-to-one mappings with insert="false" and update="false". Not very elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This is the answer Tom posted to his question:</sub>

Ah ha, think I've got it. I've updated my mappings for the NCR with this:

```
<many-to-one name="Job" class="Job">
    <column name="JobNo"></column>
    <column name="DivisionID"></column>
</many-to-one>

<many-to-one name="SpoilageJob" class="Job">
    <column name="SpoilageJobNo"></column>
    <column name="DivisionID"></column>
</many-to-one>
```